# .NET desktop client app: sockets or HTTP requests?

Tags: c#, sockets, http, client, rpc

I'm trying to set up a Windows service that can communicate asynchronously with a server, the idea is to transfer some strings. The format, well, it really doesn't matter that much.

So, in the local network, I'm cool, I even wrote a simple mobile app to test it with requests and it just works.

The problem is I now have to make it work from outside the network, and to make it happen I would have to forward the port from the router configuration, and that is really not an ideal scenario for deployment on user machines.

I've read that is the thing you normally use sockets for, but as far as I understand, at least with .NET, the server has to have the same framework (please correct me if that is not true), and in my case the server is not .NET.

Honestly, I don't know much about client-server interaction, and I have a huge conceptual blackout when reading the official Microsoft documentation, so scratch that. I've caught glimpses of WinSock and RPC from the docs, but a C# implementation feels like duct tape, and really a last resort.

That said, I reckon I need to make six questions:

1. Plain HTTP is a bad idea. Right?
2. Given the scenario, is sockets what I need? And if it is,
3. How can I implement that on the server? Also,
4. Is it better than using RPC?
5. How exactly does RPC work anyway? What do I need to read before the official docs?
6. What does a socket do to actually let the client receive an asynchronous call from outside the local network? (need it, I read it's possible)

Please forgive me if I am mixing concepts here, and thanks for reading.

NOTE to moderators: If this is a duplicate question in any way, or off topic, or invalid for any other reason, please help me first by pointing me in the right direction. I tried to give it a good search before posting, but since I am not so familiar with most concepts, I might have missed the one. Thanks!

Comment: Question isn't clear, there are many misunderstandings and too broad to explain in an answer. Keep on reading docs...

Comment: What you say is true. But hey, that's why I ask. :)

Comment: What is not clear? `too broad to explain in an answer`. (Read SO rules) So I voted it to close.... Best answer you can get is below by 
*Jeroen van Langen*, If it is enough, accept the answer, if not, then you are on the wrong site.....

Comment: Just to clarify: there is no question mark in my reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some answers here:**

*The problem is I now have to make it work from outside the network, and to make it happen I would have to forward the port from the router configuration, and that is really not an ideal scenario for deployment on user machines.*

**Portforwarding is only needed when connecting from outside the netwerk to a computer inside network (behind a router). So if a user machine connects to a computer directly on the internet, you don't need portforwarding. If a computer from the internet connects to a computer in your local network, you need to forward a port in your router. So it only affects your network.**

---

*I've read that is the thing you normally use sockets for, but as far as I understand, at least with .NET, the server has to have the same framework (please correct me if that is not true), and in my case the server is not .NET.*

**No, A socket from .NET can communicate with any implementation of socket from another language/platform. Only when communicating binary, you should be aware for endians.**

---

*Honestly, I don't know much about client-server interaction, and I have a huge conceptual blackout when reading the official Microsoft documentation, so scratch that. I've caught glimpses of WinSock and RPC from the docs, but a C# implementation feels like duct tape, and really a last resort.*

**In my opinion .NET has a solid base for handling sockets. There are many technics implemented. The async sockets are very scalable for many clients**

---

*That said, I reckon I need to make six questions:*

_Plain HTTP is a bad idea. Right?__

**Why would you consider Plain HTTP is bad? This is very usefull when the server is writting in other languages, like PHP/Python/ASP.NET anything that uses HTTP. If you're sending user private information, you should hash/encrypt it**

---

*Given the scenario, is sockets what I need? And if it is,*

**Depends on how to connect to the server..**

---

*How can I implement that on the server? Also,
Is it better than using RPC?*

**I only used RPC in form of WebServices, You can only use this, when de server has implemented it. There are some benefits to WebServices.**

---

*How exactly does RPC work anyway? What do I need to read before the official docs?*

**Read more here: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950421.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950421.aspx__)**

---

*What does a socket do to actually let the client receive an asynchronous call from outside the local network? (need it, I read it's possible)*

**There is no difference between communicating between inside and outside the network. Directly communicating via sockets is always asynchronous.**

---

**Regards,**

Comment: Hey Jeroen, thanks for the answer. The thing with plain HTTP is that I will have to port forward because the client will be in a different network, and it will be receiving async requests, I suggested it could be a bad idea because I would have to use something else, so it can't be *just* a "manual" request, and maybe that wasn't enough. My bad, I wasn't clear there. As in the post, I do admit to be kind of lost. Your answer has clarified some concepts for me. But is there another way to not have to forward the ports in the router for the client?

Comment: The client doesn't need any portforwarding. Portforwarding is only needed for incomming connections to a server behind a router. Can you describe how you're netwerk diagram looks like. For example: Where runs the server, where are the clients.

Comment: If both, server and client, are written in C#, I would go for WebServices. If your client should connect to 3rd party software, I probably choose for HTTPRequests with JSon messages

Comment: The server and the client need to listen for asynchronous requests, it's almost two servers. The server is exposed to the internet but the client is behind a router.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Websockets. I don't know why you saying that the server and client should have the same framework, this is not the case, I have used it with C# client with NodeJs backend.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kostas, I will give it a read. Is there some equivalent to WebSockets that works with Windows XP and up?

Comment: I don't think this is a bad answer...